# Does the size of the EXE affect the execution speed?

Tags: c#, vb.net, dll

I'm going to create some command line tools that make use of some large library DLL's. For security reasons I plan to embed the DLL's in the command line's EXE.

Example:
Suppose the CL's (command line tool) functionality is to just copy a file from A to B. The procedure to do this is included in a 100MB library DLL. If I would just take out the lines of code from the DLL and paste them in the CL's code then the CL would only be 10Kb.
But I don't want to do that, so I embed the full library in the CL's EXE, which will make it 101MB in size.

Please be aware that the above is just an example. I once read somewhere (cannot remember where) that Windows would only use the part of the EXE that's actually used. So if that's true then it shouldn't matter if the EXE size is 10Kb, 100MB or 1GB. I don't know if that is true, so that's why I'm asking this question.

I own the code of the DLL, so if the best solution is to not include the whole DLL but just only link to or include those code files, of the DLL project, that are used by the CL then I will go that way.

So the question is: will the 10Kb CL run faster and consume less memory than the 101MB CL?

Comment: Holy crap. Why is the compiled DLL 100 MB, but adding the source code to another project would only increase the size by 10 KB? Something is way wrong here.

Comment: It's full of random values for someone's now-defunct One-Time-Pad penpal club.

Comment: @Cody - I assume the OP meant that just copying the code for the function they're using increases their code by 10K, but if they include the whole library (with 1000s of functions they don't use), it's 100MB.

Comment: 100 MB is downright *huge* for compiled bytecode. I'd check to make sure that it doesn't include a payload of malware or porn before embedding that into my app...

Comment: Assuming your machine isn't really hard pressed for RAM, the codes going to run at the same speed either way. As there's more of it, the large 100MB app will obviously take longer to read from disk/network so it will take longer to start running which for a command line tool (that presumably does something and exits) may be noticable.

Comment: @Cody Gray - I think you are too quickly ruling out my fabulously insightful speculation! ;)

Comment: It's very hard to imagine why you would wish to use a DLL embedded in an exe rather than linking the code directly. Also, anyone that wants the DLL will be able to get it once your exe unpacks it. This question reeks of significant misunderstandings.

Comment: To all: The 100MB is just an example. I once read somewhere (cannot remember where) that Windows would only use the part of the EXE that's actually used. So if that's true then it shouldn't matter if the EXE size is 10Kb, 100MB or 1GB. As I don't know if this is true, I posted the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you're embedding the extra dll into the executable for **security reasons**, then don't.

If the program can unpack it, anyone else cans, so you're only fooling yourself if you think this will improve security, unless it is *job security* you're talking about.

Secondly, I suspect the underlying question here is quite a bit harder to answer than others might think.

If you had used a regular non-managed executable and a non-managed dll, then portions of those files would be reserved in memory space when you start the program, but only the actual bits of it you use will be mapped into physical memory.

In other words, the actual amount of physical memory the program would consume would be somewhat proportional to the amount of code you use from them and how that code is spread out. I say "somewhat" because paging into physical memory is done on a page basis, and pages have a fixed size. So a 100 byte function might end up mapping a 4KB of 8KB page (I don't recall the sizes of the pages any more) into memory. If you call a lot of such functions, and they're spread out over the address space of the code, you might end up mapping in a lot of physical memory for little code.

When it comes to managed assemblies, the picture changes somewhat. Managed code isn't mapped directly into physical memory the same way (note, I'm fuzzy on the details here because I don't know the exact details) because the code is not ready to run. Before it can be run it has to be JITted, and the JITter only JITs code on a need-to-jit basis.

In other words, if you include a humongous class in the assembly, but never use it, it might never end up being JITted and thus not use any memory.

So is the answer "no", as in it won't use more memory?

I have no idea. I suspect that there will be some effect of a larger assembly, more metadata to put into reflection tables or whatnot.

However, if you intend to place it into the executable, you either need to unpack it to disk before loading it (which would "circumvent" your "security features"), or unpack it into memory (which would require all of those 100MB of physical memory.)

So if you're concerned about using a lot of memory, here's my advice:

1. Try it, see how bad it is
2. Decide if it is worth it
3. And don't embed the extra assembly into the executable

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. Yes, I'm thinking of embedding the DLL for some security reasons. Not to make it impossible but just to make it a bit harder (a separate DLL file in a folder is easier to copy than one that's embedded). I doesn't have to be Fort Knox ;). And yes: it's all .NET code.

Comment: @Marc: Reflector creates a pretty clear division between Fort Knox-style security, and that of .NET code. You basically don't have any security at all. Don't make more work for yourself than necessary. If people want to steal your stuff, they'll find a way. Honest people won't be any more motivated to try breaking into your DLL than they would be to try and break into an EXE merged with that DLL.

Comment: @Cody: I understand. I know that you cannot protect code from stealing, but only make it a bit harder. It's however not my intention to protect the code itself furthermore, but instead of that the functionality of the library. Our software is often installed and/or used by partners that sometimes do competitive development themselves. I don't want to make it easy for them by just copy the DLL for their own projects.

Answer (score 1):

Will the smaller one run faster and consume less memory? Yes.

Will it be enough to make a difference? Who knows? If done wrong, the big one might take up about 100MB more memory (three guesses where I got that amount from)

But it sure seems awfully silly to include 100MB of 'stuff' that isn't needed...

EDIT: My "Yes" at the top here should be qualified with "infinitesimally so", and incidentally so. See comments, below.

Comment: A regular (non-managed) dll is mapped into physical memory on a need-to-map basis. A managed assembly is JITted on a need-to-jit basis. Are you *sure* it will use less memory?

Comment: I'm really not sure of anything with this question, except that the differences are likely to be so tiny (unless something really 'bad' was done) as to not make any difference at all. No; it should not directly use more memory *because it's loading unused code* (since it's NOT loading unused code)... but as my mind whirs, it strikes me that an extra 101MB of potential 'distance' between locations to find stuff might end up causing an extra byte or two to get allocated somewhere... but that doesn't matter.

Comment: I updated my original question with this mindset. So, if I understand you correctly, what you're saying is exactly what I was thinking: only the part of the EXE that's actually used is loaded so there's no real disadvantage in including the whole DLL, no matter how big it is?

Comment: *Barring anything "weird" that you might be doing* yes, that is correct. There is no real difference at all. The 100MB thing threw us all off a bit, but even there, likely, there would be no difference. But now, knowing more... I think you're barking up the wrong tree, but that's not the subject of this question